# what happened when you load a document at a URI that already exists in the Marklogic database?

Tags: marklogic

what happened when you load a document at a URI that already exists in the Marklogic database?

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? What happened?

Comment: See first two sentences of the [xdmp:document-insert()](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:document-insert) documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You overwrite the previous stored version.

you can also simply try this out with an

```
fn:doc("uri");
xdmp:document-insert("uri", ...<your content here>... );
fn:doc("uri");
```

and see that the output matches what you have just inserted

Answer (score 0):

The previously stored document at that URI is overwritten (including permissions, collections, or quality if specified in the function call) **if the user has a role that has update permissions on that URI**. If the user does not have update permissions for the URI, an error will be thrown.